# How to change the view angle using a cusor

Tags: 3d-view

After creating an object, how to change the view angle using a mouse cusor so that I can view the object from a different angle?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How is changing the view angle related to creating a new object? Have you tried using mouse3 click ?

Comment: Hi, I gave this question a downvote because it does not show any research effort. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/index.html Or some beginner tutorials for the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Click down the middle mouse button (scroll wheel) and move the mouse

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I think I found the answer.  I have to click the hand icon on the right then use my mouse.  Thanks.